# How can I match up rows with columns in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-desktop

I have a Tableau report that is using data from an MySQL database.  The query is just a select statement that returns all the rows for an exam.

In Columns,  I have the `QuestionText` which looks fine.

In Rows, I have `studentLastName` but now I want to show the answer each user selected for each question.

But whenever I drag the `studentAnswer` column over to a row, it shows the selected answer for every question...but I only want to show the answer for the question that is for that column.

For example, if I have the following questions in the columns:

> "What color is on the screen?"  |  "How old is your instructor?"  |  "What
> month is it?"

When I drag the `studentAnswer` over to a row, it does this:

```
"What color is on the screen?"  |  "What day is it?"  |  "What month is it?"

Blue  Monday   May                Blue  Monday  May     Blue  Monday  May
```

Is there a way to fix this?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these two fixes first:

1. Bring `studentAnswer` to *Text* in the "Marks Pane" while leaving `QuestionText` and `studentLastName` in their respective places
2. If you just want a grid similar to your select query, bring all your fields to rows and sort as you need fit.

If these don't resolve it, I think something funky may be happening in your SQL script were each answer is linked to each question.